# Can i use routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); on MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to create a controller on MVC4 
and i need links on special attribute 
so when I open RouteConfig.cs 
I can't found this : 
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
and give me an error . 
So how can i make a special attribute to the each control and action on MVC 4

Comment: Are you trying to enable attribute routing ?

Comment: the attribute routing is enable . But if i need to make a special attribute on controller like this [Route ("Cars/Index")] . I can't

Comment: `and give me an error` What error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionattributeroutingextensions.mapmvcattributeroutes(v=vs.118).aspx) extension method only available in MVC version 5 or higher, because `RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions` class doesn't exist in previous versions. Using that method in MVC 4 or below will show this error:

> 'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'MapMvcAttributeRoutes' and no extension method
>   'MapMvcAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type
>   'RouteCollection' could be found.

If you want to use attribute routing in MVC versions older than MVC 5, install [`AttributeRouting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/) package then use `AddRoutesFromController()` method to add controller name into routing configuration inside `RegisterRoutes` method (`ControllerName` belongs to any controller class name):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapAttributeRoutes(config =>
    {
        config.AddRoutesFromController<ControllerName>();
    });
}
```

Then, you can use `RouteAttribute` (and `RoutePrefixAttribute`) similar to MVC 5 fashion:

```
[RoutePrefix("Cars")]
public class CarsController : Controller
{
    [Route("Cars/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You can found detailed information of `AttributeRouting` package usage [here](http://mccalltd.github.io/AttributeRouting/#asp-net-mvc).

Comment: where should i put this method ?             routes.MapAttributeRoutes(config =>
            {
                config.AddRoutesFromController<ControllerName>();
            });

Comment: You can add `MapAttributeRoutes` in `RegisterRoutes` method inside `RouteConfig` as mentioned in [this wiki](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/1.-Getting-Started). Then modify route registration in `Global.asax` (i.e. `Application_Start()` method) to set it.